# Some questions concerning the construction of the line integral in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, riemann-integration, line-integrals, gauge-integral

I am comparing two ways of defining the integral along a path of a function of complex domain and value. One is the one given in *Conway's Functions of one Complex Variable* and the other is given in *Stein's Complex Analysis*. The one given by Conway proceeds in the fashion of the Riemann-Stieltjes manner: first begins by defining functions of bounded variation of a complex value with domain a compact interval of the reals (which he calls "Rectifiable Curve") and then proceeds to prove that every continuous function with domain a compact interval is integrable with respect to a rectifiable curve.

Stein's approach is simpler: he defines the integral of a continuous function $f: G \subset \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ along a continuously differentiable curve $\gamma : [a,b] \to G$ to be

$\int_{\gamma} f = \int_{a}^{b} f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) dt$

(Here I was forced to assume that if $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{C}$ is a function such that $Re(f)$ and $Im(f)$ are Riemann integrable, then we define
$\int_{a}^b f = \int_{a}^b Re(f) + i \int_a^b Im(f)$)

I get that Conway's approach is more general to Stein's in the sense that the deffinition of Stein is just the particular  case of Conway's deffinition with the restrictions stated above.

What are the advantages of the definition by Conway with respect to Stein's? One is that it is more general, but this advantage seems to general for me, so, I want to know in which particular cases is the definition given by Conway draws advantage to Stein's.

Also, when I had a course involving the Riemann Integral in the reals, the Riemann-Stieltjes approach was also used. Then, a year later, I began reading Bartle's *A modern theory of integration*, in which the Kurzweil-Henstock construction of the generalized Riemann integral is given and, this approach is more general and simpler than the Riemann-Stieltjes, so I am wondering if it would be beneficial to give a Kurzweil-Henstock approach to the line integral in $\mathbb{C}$, and if so, why isn't any book (at least of my knowledge, correct me if there exists one in some text) giving this construction?

Comment: One difference is that not every rectifiable curve is smooth, or even piecewise smooth. Iirc the cantor function can yield a rectifiable curve with uncountably many points where smoothness fails at uncountably many points. As to the choice of integral: it's a long standing problem even in real analysis to decide which integral to teach (Riemann, Darboux, Lebesgue, gauge integral, etc). Each tends to have its own advantages (e.g. simplicity to define in Riemann case, L^2 theory for Lebesgue, etc). It really just comes down to author preference as the choice rarely matters.

Comment: The choice of integrals matters even less in the complex case than the real case. This is because contour integrals are homotopy invariant, so you can always replace the curve with a simpler curve up to homotopy; in practice every contour of interest is piecewise smooth.